# Changing MongoDB default data location prevents remote access. Ubuntu server 20.4

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

I have been struggling for this on for a few days. I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 400 and installed Ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS. I have successfully set up mongoDB and can access it remotely. Now I want to change the location of the data being saved to a 500GB SSD plugged into the pi.

I have changed the mongod.conf file as below

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
#  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  dbPath: /mnt/mongo/data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

As you can see I just changed the dbPath to a mounted drive.

Now to run mongod I have to run it with the command

```
mongod --dbpath=/mnt/mongo/data/
```

I have to fix a failed to unlink socket error using

`sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

Then I can connect fine on the PI but I can no longer connect remotely. I get error

```
Network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server 192.168.1.99:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 192.168.1.99:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused
```

I was under the impression that removing the /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock was the correct fix for that error and that mongo creates a new one on start up. I'm not sure if that is causing the problem with connecting remotely or I'm missing something when moving the default dbPath to the SSD.

How do I change the Mongo default db path and maintain the ability to access it remotely on Ubuntu server?

Comment: You need to tell the mongod to listen on all interfaces (mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 )  otherways your mongod is listening only on localhost , and better you start it with the conf file: mongod --config xxx.conf

Comment: Thanks I added --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 and it worked. But I thought it would have got this info from the existing mongod.conf file. So it appears if you open mongod using --dpath='something' then it does not use the default mongod.conf file. This is not very clear in the docs. Thanks though I can access remotely now. You can expand your comment to an answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you added only the --dbpath option in the command line the rest of settings are ignored ( defaults are used).
Best is to add all configuration settings in the mongodb.conf file and start the mongodb service with the config file as follow:

```
 mongod --config mongod.conf
```

Hint:

If you want the mongod to start as daemon from the command line you will need to add the following option in the mongod.conf file:

```
 processManagement:
   fork: true
```

Also for SSD you may want to disable diagnostic data collection(FTDC) with:

```
setParameter: 
  diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled: false
```

And also mount the partition with noatime
( to avoid unnecessary writes to SSD)